# Make config available through an entire ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

I am creating a gem where I'd like to define some constants to be available.

In my actual `gemspec`, I added the following:

```
config = File.expand_path('../config', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(config) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(config)

require 'constants.rb'
```

In `constants.rb` I have a simple var defined: `$FOO = "Hello, World!"`

Then in my `lib/gem_name/core.rb`, I'm attempting to `puts $FOO` but it doesn't seem to be available. No error, just comes up blank. Am I not understanding how gem dependencies and the require tree works here?

** UPDATE **

I have also tried just adding a `config` directory directly underneath `lib` which is in the LOAD_PATH already. then in my library, I am attempting to `require config/constants`, but that's saying it cannot load such a file.

I have also tried just moving `constants.rb` to the lib directory directly and requiring that, and it's warning me that it cannot load such file. Something is terribly wonky.

Comment: **DO NOT** modify `$LOAD_PATH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/04/02/using-gemspecs-as-intended/),

> When your gem is built, Rubygems will run that code and create a static representation. This means it’s fine to pull your gem’s version or other shared details out of your library itself. Do not, however, use other libraries or dependencies.

That means that `require 'constants.rb'` and `$LOAD_PATH.unshift(...)` etc are run when you build the gem. At runtime, it doesn't change the `$LOAD_PATH` or cause a global require. Use [`gem.require_paths`](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#require_paths) instead to modify `$LOAD_PATH` at runtime.

For example, in your gemspec, use

```
gem.files += Dir['config/**/*']
gem.require_paths = %w[lib config]
```

Then in places where `$FOO` is required, use

```
require 'constants'
```

#### Side Notes

- You don't need to include the `.rb` extension when using `require`.
- Make sure all the files you need are in [`gem.files`](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#files).

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the response. I am trying to do this actually as we speak, and when I install the gem I get the following: `file 'config' not found` it's not liking that option in gem.require_path for some reason.

Comment: Oops. It's supposed to be `require_paths` with an 's'.

Comment: Same thing with the require_paths directive as well. No dice.

Comment: Ah I figured out the problem. I didn't `git add` the directory/files yet and gem.files was using `git` to see what files are a part of the gem with `git ls-files`, thank you again

Comment: Np. Glad you fixed it.